# Display data in table on ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am submitting the form from ajax, and after ajax success i want to display all data in table tr td.

**Below is my response which i got on ajax success and i want to load inside table on ajax success, but its displaying blank table.**

```
{"raildata":null,"killdata":[{"id":146,"acct_id":1885,"AcctNo":"UP2357"},{"id":145,"acct_id":1885,"AcctNo":"UP2357"}]}
```

**Below is my jquery ajax code which i tried, but its not displaying data after form submit on success.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#killfrm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?= Router::url(['controller' => 'Killsheets', 'action' => 'addKillsheet']) ?>',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#ibox1').children('.ibox-content').toggleClass('sk-loading');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                    var trHTML = ''; 
                    $(response).each(function (i,value) {

                        trHTML += response.killdata.map(function(killdata) {
                          return '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + killdata.id + '</td><td>' + killdata.AcctNo + '</td></tr>';
                        });

                        trRailHTML += response.raildata.map(function(raildata) {
                          return '<tr class="gradeA"><td>' + raildata.rail_no + '</td><td>' + raildata.scale_no + '</td><td><button title="View" class="btn btn-default btn btn-xs tblbtn">View</button></td></tr>';
                        }); 

                    });
                $('#txtcount').val(sum);    
                $('#listRail').html(trRailHTML);                                 
                $('#listKill').html(trHTML);

        },
            error: function(response) {         
                console.log(response);          
            }        
        });
    });
});
```

**Below is my HTML table**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
                                        <thead>
                                           <tr>
                                            <th>Sheet#</th>
                                            <th>Acc #</th>
                                             <th>Action</th>
                                          </tr>
                                        </thead>                                         
                                        <tbody id="listKill"> </tbody>
                                  </table>
```

Comment: why don't you use datatables? https://datatables.net/

Comment: Can u plz help me to out from this.. when i try same code on textbox blur events it will work for me, but same code wont work after ajax success. bcz i am submiting form and after submit i want to display all database data inside table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for get json data in ajax response you need to pass ajax options :

```
dataType:"json"
```

go with below example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'Your Url',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(response) {
          response == here you get object you can get any value by object key

        }
       });
```

your json response:

```
{"raildata":null,"killdata":[{"id":146,"acct_id":1885,"AcctNo":"UP2357"},{"id":145,"acct_id":1885,"AcctNo":"UP2357"}]}
```

you can get result by using `response` variable like below

```
console.log(response.killdata);
console.log(response.raildata);
```

try above if you get any help

Comment: Yes i missed to put datatype: json,  Thank you very much. but how to refresh table with new data which i added, bcz its not adding new response

Comment: ok i will add new answers for that..

Answer (score 1):

you can pass `$.each`:
script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#killfrm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?= Router::url(['controller' => 'Killsheets', 'action' => 'addKillsheet']) ?>',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#ibox1').children('.ibox-content').toggleClass('sk-loading');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                    let trHTML = ''; 
                    let killData = response.killdata;
                    let raildata = response.raildata;

                    $.each(killData, function(kill) {
                        let killid = kill.id;
                        let killacct_id = kill.acct_id;
                        let killAcctNo = kill.AcctNo;
                        trHTML += '<tr>';
                        trHTML += '<td>'+killid+'</td>';
                        trHTML += '<td>'+killacct_id+'</td>';
                        trHTML += '<td>'+killAcctNo+'</td>';
                        trHTML += '</tr>';
                    });


                $('#listRail').html(raildata);                                 
                $('#listKill').html(trHTML);

            },
            error: function(response) {         
                console.log(response);          
            }        
        });
    });
});
```

you get result html `trHTML` in id of `#listKill`:

html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sheet#</th>
<th>Acc #</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>                                         
<tbody id="listKill">result goes here </tbody>
</table>
```

you can get any response data from `response.objectkey = get value`

Answer (score 0):

Table body is appended like this:

Assin id to your table

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id='my_table'>
```

Add this row to add the new rows

```
$("#my_table tbody").append(trHTML);
```

Comment: Already tried but wont work in my case